# Does hitting one type of deduction cap exhaust deductions for other types of donations?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, irs

For appreciated securities the IRS allows certain caps on how much of AGI can be deducted.

Here is a chart: http://www.nptrust.org/donor-advised-funds/daf-vs-foundation/

The short version is 20% (of AGI) for a private foundation, 30% for donor-advised funds and 50% for direct gift.

If I give the 20%+ of AGI to a foundation and thus exhaust that possibility for deduction... can I still deduct my direct giving if it's under 50%?

I.e. are there separate buckets of potential deduction or is it all one big bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Each donation event has its own individual deduction cap (20/30/50), but the only overall deduction cap is the 50% one.  So you could theoretically hit two separate 20% deduction caps and then still donate another 10% of your `AGI` before you hit your 50% overall deduction cap for the year.

See [Pub 526 #Limits on Deductions](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000229802) for a detailed explanation and an example.

Also note that when you "exhaust" your deductions for one year, that just means you can't claim them that year.  You can still carry over any remaining donations (or portions of donations) to the next year.